# How to profile java web application running as maven plugin (tomcat) with yourkit?

Tags: java, maven, profiling, yourkit

I am running Java web application as mvn tomcat:run. I've connected it with yourkit. But these fields are disabled:

JSP/Servlet requests:
count, per second
request duration (average, max)
Database connections:
how many opened and closed, per second
live time (average, max)
Database queries:
count, per second
call duration (average, max)

Could anyone help me in activating them? I tried to make them "on" on probes tab. But it didn't help.

Comment: Seems like Yourkit can't detect the Tomcat inside of Maven.